# AngularJS: Content Type header is always set to application/json instead of multipart/form-data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I trying to implement simple file upload by using the multipart/form-data.

However the request header content type is set to application/json.

Below is my code:

```
uploadFiles: function (files, successFunction, failFunction) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    angular.forEach(files, function (file, index) {
       formData.append('file', file.file);
    });

    $http.post(getServiceAddress() + '/api/upload', formData, {
       transformRequest: angular.identity,
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': undefined
       }
    }).success(successFunction).error(failFunction);
}
```

Request header & request payload:

[image]

[image]

Notice the Content-Type header is still in application/json.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an [$http intercepter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) adding headers for `Authorization` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Look at that code. It is likely also overriding the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @georgeawg, solved it based on your finding by disable the overriding `Content-Type`. Thank you.